# How to send data over CAN-Bus using ESP32 Module using MicroPython?

Tags: esp32, can-bus, micropython

I have an ESP32 module connected to my computer. I am using Thonny IDE to program my ESP32 device using micropython code. I am trying to send data over CAN bus but I m getting error.

**code:**

```
from machine import CAN

can = CAN(mode=CAN.NORMAL, baudrate=500000, pins=('P22', 'P23'))
can.send(id=12, data=bytes([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]))
can.recv()
```

**error:**

```
ImportError: can't import name CAN
```

Comment: @gspr why? Is it not allowed?

Comment: [No it isn't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: And even if it were allowed: a screenshot is clearly a far less suited way to read code than the code itself.

Comment: @gspr ok removed.

Comment: [The ESP32 build of MicroPython doesn't seem to support the CAN API.](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/issues/5087)

Comment: @gre_gor thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing this answer, according to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/issues/5087), the CAN API doesn't seem to be supported on the ESP32 build of MicroPython.

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/pull/7381) for an implementation, but is currently not working.